# Does Database.SaveResult, Database.DeleteResult, etc. implement a public interface?

Tags: dml, update, delete, interface, database.insert

The various DML operations (insert, update, delete, etc.) all return results with very similar methods and properties.

It is not uncommon, as a developer, that I should want to handle these results in similar ways.

Is there an interface that I can compose to instead of the concretions?

Answer (score 5):

No, they do not implement a common interface. As a workaround to this, I created a wrapper class that does this:

```
class DmlResult {
    Id recordId;
    Integer rowIndex;
    Boolean success;
    Database.Error[] errors;
    DmlResult(Boolean success, Id recordId, Database.Error[] errors, Integer rowIndex) {
        this.success = success;
        this.recordId = recordId;
        this.errors = errors;
        this.rowIndex = rowIndex;
    }
}
```

From there, I have a DmlResultList class that normalizes the data:

```
class DmlResultList implements Iterable<DmlResult> {
    DmlResult[] genResults;
    DmlResultList(Database.SaveResult[] results) {
        genResults = new DmlResult[0];
        for(Database.SaveResult result: results) {
            genResults.add(new DmlResult(result.isSuccess(), result.getId(), result.getErrors(), genResults.size()));
        }
    }
    DmlResultList(Database.DeleteResult[] results) {
        genResults = new DmlResult[0];
        for(Database.DeleteResult result: results) {
            genResults.add(new DmlResult(result.isSuccess(), result.getId(), result.getErrors(), genResults.size()));
        }
    }
    // ... other result types
}
```

Once you have this, you can then create a common handler:

```
DmlResultList results = new DmlResultList(Database.insert(records, false));
```

Comment: Ive come up with a similar solution, but then, of course, we need to iterate over the list to perform the conversion and we are instantiating a lot of objects... I was hoping we can avoid that....

Answer (score 3):

There is no interface implemented by the various `Database.*Result` classes, which do all implement mostly the same methods (the exception being `Database.UpsertResult`, which has one additional method).

However, the classes are serializable, as is the underlying `Database.Error`. So what you can do is create your own unified class implementing the same "interface" (data model, really), serialize your `Database.*Results` to JSON, and then deserialize them into your own class, to avoid writing any non-generic code.

You are, of course, taking the performance hit (which I have not myself measured) of performing JSON serialization and deserialization around all of your DML operations.

### Unified Class

```
public class DatabaseResult {
    public class Error {
        public String statusCode;
        public String message;
        public List<String> fields;
    }
    public Id id;
    public Boolean success;
    public List<Error> errors;
}
```

### Example Code

```
Account a = new Account();

Database.SaveResult[] srs = Database.insert(new List<Account>{a}, false);

System.debug('Toto: ' + JSON.serializePretty(srs));
System.debug('Ea: ' + JSON.serializePretty(srs[0]));

DatabaseResult q = (DatabaseResult )JSON.deserialize(JSON.serializePretty(srs[0]), DatabaseResult.class);
System.debug('Q: ' + JSON.serializePretty(q));
```

Comment: Great minds think alike.

Comment: I'm more comfortable with your solution; bouncing between JSON and the object model always feels a bit fragile to me.

Comment: Cheers for the response...  I already had a solution similar to Sfdcfoxs...  I was hoping there would be an interface we could use to improve upon it.